# Bind ajax result to Controller

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs

I'm loading an html in Controller to display when an event is fired. I'm using the ngSanitize and ng-bind-html to draw the content:

```
loadData.getLargeNavUser().then(function(data){
  $scope.content = $sce.trustAsHtml(data);
}
```

The problem is that the content loaded have a Controller but Angular don't bind the content to the Controller.
any idea?

Comment: Are you saying the data in the ng-bind-html is not being processed further by angular?  You might need to manually call $compile on the code but it's not entirely clear.  A simplified plnkr.co showing the problem in action would help.

Comment: yes. this is the problem. I'm doing the compile with the loaded data like this: $compile(data)($scope) but now if I add this to $scope.content angular bring me an error. I can try to do a plnkr but I don't have to much time. Thank you.

Comment: What's the error exactly... sorry haven't run into this scenario with using ng-bind-html with externally loaded data that I'm also trying to hook into the controller so I can't give a direct answer.

Comment: @shaunhusain this is the example. thanks http://plnkr.co/edit/iSGT5VTmCrLMtIVhSWnT?p=preview

Comment: @shaunhusain I'm trying this http://plnkr.co/edit/iSGT5VTmCrLMtIVhSWnT?p=preview
but don't bind neither